# Can an Amazon Quicksight dashboard analysis export to JSON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

The company that I work for looking at potentially using Amazon Quicksight as a BI platform to show insights on some of our data. While I know that Quicksight allows you to embed dashboards and customize their data through the use of parameters and drill downs, can you access/export the rendered data via the Javascript SDK?

For instance, if a user wanted to filter down the list of people within the dashboard, would I have the ability to access that dataset and then perform an action upon it; like send an email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get data from the [Amazon QuickSight SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/QuickSight.html).

Review the [API reference guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to understand the actions you can take using the SDK.  Based on your question, you may want to review `DescribeAnalysis` ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAnalysis.html)) which responds with:
`A metadata structure that contains summary information for the analysis that you're describing`.

Answer (score 0):

Quicksight provides functionality to download data from the visuals in dashboards. It can be downloaded in csv / excel format.

Also, you can take a print of your dashboard.